# "Failed to load ad : 3" - How to solve this?

Tags: android, admob

I created my admob account 1 year ago and everything was working fine until ads suddenly stopped showing in my app and I was getting `Failed to load ad : 3`.

This is happening from the past **45 days**. I'm getting 0 requests, 0 impressions and 0 everything.

I have no idea what I have to do. Does anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: Did you have any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, I am still facing the same problem